# Difference between Universal linking and old URL scheme in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-links

Could you please tell me the main difference in coding when changing from old custom url scheme to universal binding(Deep linking in iOS) introduced by iOS from iOS 9 onwards?

I believe that deep linking is still possible using custom url scheme. Is that correct? Thanks in advance.

I have  referred the following links,

https://blog.branch.io/ios-9-2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links/

https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-deep-linking-guide-transitioning-to-universal-links/

But I would like to get a simple answer. So I rely on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Universal link: more suited for web that all pages are linking with the app, you bind a pattern on your app and a json on your page for ios to recognize, dont need know the pattern of the other app to open it, more secure

URL scheme: create a pattern and your web redirect to that url so iOS can recognize, it show error if the app is not install, need to know the app scheme to open (also need list in plist)

They can be use together

Answer (score 2):

That would be incorrect: beginning with iOS 9.2, Apple discontinued support for opening apps via URI Scheme. Universal Links were introduced with iOS 9.0 and as of iOS 9.2 they have been the only way to open apps via links.

URI Schemes were easier to configure than Universal Links, as they required little more than a single entry in the project's .plist file and code to handle the link in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and openURL functions of the AppDelegate class.

Universal Links rely on a remote "AASA" file to map links to apps. Configuration involves creating and hosting the AASA file and adding the associated-domains entitlement to the app (you do not need to worry about the AASA file if you are using Branch).

Universal Linking requires that there be code to handle referring links in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and continueUserActivity functions of the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 2):

No, customer URL scheme's would be removed in the upcoming versions of iOS since it is not secure and has a lot of privacy issues i.e, App A can get to know whether you are using B, like Facebook can know whether you are using Tinder. So universal links is the right way to go now.